# Soving an inequality involving exponential

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, with $ab>0$. For which interval of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ is the following true? 
$$
e^{\alpha a}\geq \alpha b+1
$$

Fabio

Comment: Where does this problem come from? I guess you would have to use the Lambert-W function for this.

Comment: Thanks it comes from a proof of convexity of a function.

Comment: Bad idea to use $\alpha$ and $a$ in the same formula.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very easy to solve. Also, it's usually two intervals.

If you turn the inequality around, then you get one interval, with $0$ at one end, and where the other end is a bit difficult to solve for, involving branches of the Lambert $W$ function. For instance, for [$a = 1, b = 2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex+%3D+2x+%2B+1), we get approximately the interval $[0,1.26]$.

Assuming $a = 1$ and $b\neq 1$, fiddling around on WolframAlpha leads me to believe that the general non-zero point of equality$^*$ seems to be
$$
\alpha = -W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{be^{1/b}}\right) - \frac1b
$$
where $W_{-1}$ is one branch of the Lambert $W$ function.

$^*$ See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(x)+-+bx+-+1+where+x+%3D+-ProductLog%5B-1,+-1%2F(b+exp(1%2Fb))%5D-1%2Fb

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am actually interested in the case when $a<b$. Fabio

Comment: @Fabio Sure. That works fine.